# Problem with loading picture from website to WPF Image using URL

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a snake game. As in the title - I've tried to load a picture from website to the source of WPF Image using URL. My goal was to load a random picture from website as a bitmap every time the snake collects the food on the map, but the most important thing was that it shouldn't be loaded when the program executes, but after the snake collects the food. So I've created a string array, where I placed 5 url links to the pictures from the website and then I wanted to use Random() to choose a random link to the picture and place it to the source of WPF Image. But when the snake collects the food, nothing happens. And my question is: is my code wrong? Here's my code:

XAML CODE

```xml
<Window x:Class="Snake_Game.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Snake_Game"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Snake The Game" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered" 
        KeyUp="Window_KeyUp">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="8">
        <Canvas Name="GameBoard" 
                ClipToBounds="True" 
                Background="Black" 
                Height="1000" 
                Width="1000">
            <Rectangle x:Name="ScoreBoard" 
                       Fill="#FF7B2D96" 
                       Height="1000" 
                       Canvas.Left="706" 
                       Stroke="Black" 
                       Width="294"/>
            <Label x:Name="PointsPanel" 
                   Content="POINTS" 
                   Canvas.Left="804" 
                   Canvas.Top="27" 
                   Height="29" 
                   Width="95" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                   FontSize="14" 
                   Background="#FFE72626"/>
            <Image x:Name="ImagePanel" 
                   Height="355" 
                   Canvas.Left="724" 
                   Canvas.Top="272" 
                   Width="266" 
                   Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
                   StretchDirection="DownOnly" 
                   MaxHeight="355"
                   MaxWidth="266">
                <Image.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush/>
                </Image.OpacityMask>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="Score" 
                   Content="" 
                   Canvas.Left="804" 
                   Canvas.Top="61" 
                   Height="50" 
                   Width="95" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                   FontSize="36" 
                   FontFamily="SimSun"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Method used to load a random picture (from string array):

```cs
private void GetRandomImage()
{       
    string[] images = 
    {
        "http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/28/15/25/snake-653639_1280.jpg",
        "http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/25/14/54/snake-579682_1280.jpg",
        "http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/28/15/25/rattlesnake-653642_1280.jpg",
        "http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/10/10/05/07/grass-snake-60546_1280.jpg",
        "http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/12/14/16/46/snake-3237_1280.jpg"
    };

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[rnd.Next(images.Length)]));

    ImagePanel.Source = bitmapImage;                   
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Image source doesn't update image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548144/wpf-image-source-doesnt-update-image)

Comment: Remove the empty OpacityMask.

Comment: @sous2817 I've tried this also, but the OpacityMask was the problem :) anyway thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `OpacityMask`. You do not set `ImageSource` of `ImageBrush`, so there is no reason to have `OpacityMask`.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="8">
    <Canvas Name="GameBoard" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Black" Height="1000" Width="1000"
            >
        <Rectangle x:Name="ScoreBoard" Fill="#FF7B2D96" Height="1000" Canvas.Left="706" Stroke="Black" Width="294"/>
        <Label x:Name="PointsPanel" Content="    POINTS" Canvas.Left="804" Canvas.Top="27" Height="29" Width="95" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Background="#FFE72626"/>
        <Image x:Name="ImagePanel" Height="355" Canvas.Left="724" Canvas.Top="272" Width="266" Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" StretchDirection="DownOnly" MaxHeight="355"
               MaxWidth="266">
        </Image>
        <Label x:Name="Score" Content="" Canvas.Left="804" Canvas.Top="61" Height="50" Width="95" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="36" FontFamily="SimSun"/>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```